# How to not display browse widget error message?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4gl. I have created a window with a browser and some buttons added like ADD, DELETE, EDIT. Here the issue is if I click the "EDIT" button without selecting any record from the browser then its giving progress error message. My concern here is I don't wish to show this type of error to a client instead I would like to show what I have written. The attached image is the progress error. Please take a code below.

```
IF BROWSE-28:SELECT-FOCUSED-ROW() IN FRAME {&FRAME-NAME}  THEN DO:
   /* means record selected, do the logic */
END.
ELSE DO:
   /* record not selected from the browser, throw an error*/
   MESSAGE "Select at least one record" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION BUTTONS OK.
END.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try
     IF BROWSE-28:NUM-SELECTED > 0 THEN

Before that